# Can't figure out how to set the value of EM_SETLIMITTEXT with winapi in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

My question is fairly simple, so I'll get straight to the point.

My code to create a text box in my gui application is below:

```
CreateWindowW(L"edit",L"12345",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER|ES_MULTILINE|EM_SETLIMITTEXT,50,230,680,388,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

You can see that I have included "EM_SETLIMITTEXT." My goal is to set the maximum amount of characters to 2000. However, I do not know how to set the value for this and I am especially confused since I am fairly new to c++.

Comment: EM_* are Window Messages, while ES_* are Window Styles.

Comment: And `EN_*` are notifications. The same `S` / `M` / `N` naming scheme is also used with other controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EM_SETLIMITTEXT` is a message, not a window style, so as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setlimittext) you should write:

```
HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindowW(L"edit",L"12345",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER|ES_MULTILINE,50,230,680,388,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
SendMessage (hWndEdit, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, 2000, 0);
```